# RabbitMQ HTTP API returning 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: rabbitmq

Using RabbitMQ localhost and trying to use his API.. when i Call from postman it's work fine.

[image]

But i'm trying to use this API inside my app code and I'm getting 401 error:

```
const test = {
  count: 5,
  ackmode: 'ack_requeue_true',
  encoding: 'auto',
  truncate: 50000
}

  testPost() {
    fetch('http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2F/QA.MOBILE/get', {
      method: 'post',
      mode: 'no-cors',
      body: JSON.stringify(test),
      headers: {Authorization: 'Basic ' + btoa('guest:guest'), Accept: 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    });
  }
```

POST http://localhost:15672/api/queues/%2F/QA.MOBILE/get net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)

I'm missing something?

thanks

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error. I tried using the `requests` library in `python`. And it works fine. Make sure you are passing the right credentials

Comment: Hello @bumblebee I found the problem..


I can't set: mode: 'no-cors' in my fetch..

And I must add on advanced.config this settings to allow CORS:

[
 {rabbitmq_management,[
 {cors_allow_origins, ["*"]}
 ]}
].


Than worked fine :)

thanks,
Alan

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem myself. Even though my issue was not CORS related, I thought I would document the issue here in case future readers have the same problem.

My issue was that I was not correctly base64ing the user credentials.  From a browser you can just call any of the [RabbitMQ API endpoints](https://pulse.mozilla.org/api/) like this:

http://somename:somepassword@servername:15672/api/cluster-name

But when calling it programatically, you need to remove the credentials from the url and base 64 them instead.

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("GET"), "http://servername:15672/api/cluster-name"))
    {
        var base64authorization = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"somename:somepassword"));
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", $"Basic {base64authorization}");

        var response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == true)
        {
            string jsonContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is C# but it would be the same process for Java, etc.